# Does not change the icon after switching the theme

Tags: flutter, animation, button, icons, themes

There is an **animated_theme_switcher**
package and assigned a code to change the icon after switching, but it does not change .. what code is needed?
Help please .. I will be grateful
my code:

```
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    ),
                                  child: ThemeSwitcher(
                                    clipper: const ThemeSwitcherCircleClipper(),
                                    builder: (context)
                                    {
                                      return IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          var themeName =
                                          ThemeModelInheritedNotifier
                                              .of(context)
                                              .theme
                                              .brightness ==
                                              Brightness.light
                                              ? 'dark'
                                              : 'light';
                                          var service = await ThemeService.instance
                                            ..save(themeName);
                                          var theme = service.getByName(themeName);
                                          ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: theme);
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(ThemeModelInheritedNotifier
                                            .of(context)
                                            .theme == Brightness.light ? Icons.light_mode_outlined : Icons.dark_mode_outlined),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the screen where you want to make them switch with ThemeSwitchingArea widget, as it has shown in the following example:

```
ThemeSwitchingArea(
        child: Builder(builder: (context)
    {
      return IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var themeName =
          ThemeModelInheritedNotifier
              .of(context)
              .theme
              .brightness ==
              Brightness.light
              ? 'dark'
              : 'light';
          var service = await ThemeService.instance
            ..save(themeName);
          var theme = service.getByName(themeName);
          ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: theme);
        },
        icon: Icon(ThemeModelInheritedNotifier
            .of(context)
            .theme == Brightness.light ? Icons.light_mode_outlined : Icons.dark_mode_outlined),
      );
    },);
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand where( ... Above, I added the code from where it starts

Comment: figured it out

.of(context)
.theme
.brightness == Brightness.light ? ...

Comment: please study animated_theme_switcher docs completely